# Trying to update entities from a disconnected entity

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Ok, each and every time I get into this situation, I struggle back and forth until I find a way to solve it (and that is usually not the way I would have liked to solve it).

What I'm talking about is disconnected entities in EF that should update existing entities in the database.

I'll give an example of my problem here (this example is the last time I got into this problem that caused me to write this question).

I have a WCF service that uses Entity Framework as well. The other program that have added a service reference to my service have gotten proxy versions of the Entities as normal.

The case is that the consumer of the service now construct a object of this proxy class, and call the method UpdateEntity on the WCF service. This entity has a foreign key to another type of entities, and the primary key of the entity I want to link this new entity to is also sent as a parameter to this method. In this case, I want the entity with the same primary key in the database to be updated. It seems simple enough right?

My method looks something like this now:

```
public bool ChangeEntity(MyEntity entity, int otherTableForignKey)
{
  //first I verify that the entity to update exist in the system
  var entitytochange = entityContext.MyEntities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == entity.Name);
  if (systemtochange == null) return false;
  try
  {
    entity.ForignEntity = entityContext.ForeignEntities.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == otherTableForignKey);
    //code for updating the entity should go here, but I'm nor sure what
    entityContext.SaveChanges();
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I tried many different combinations of `ApplyCurrentValues`, `Attach`, setting `ObjectState` to Modified and so on, but I get either the error message that I can't add a new entity with the same key as an existing entity, that the object state of the new object can't be Added and so on.

So my question is: What is the best way to do this without writing code that looks like a big hack.

The only way I got this working now was to just set the properties of `entitytochange` manually with the properties of `entity`, but it is a bad solution since any added properties to `MyEntity` will break the code if I don't remember to add code in this method as well, and it seems there really should be another way that is better.

**EDIT**

When I put `entityContext.MyEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);` where my comment is put above, I get the following exception on this line:

```
The existing object in the ObjectContext is in the Added state. Changes can only be applied when the existing object is in an unchanged or modified state.
```

However, if I remove this line above `entity.ForignEntity = entityContext.ForeignEntities.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == otherTableForignKey);` then the `ApplyCurrentValues` works without any problems.

Why would me setting the ForeignEntity of the object set it to Added state? So it seems that setting a Property on the Detached entity, attaches it to the context with a state of added?

Comment: What exactly happens if you use `ApplyCurrentValues`?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - See my Edit above.